# How to set a upper bandwidth limit in Squid

Tags: squid

Is there any way to set a upper bandwidth limit such that at any point of
time the total bandwidth from Squid service will not cross the upper limit?

Warm Regards

Supratik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [delay pools](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/DelayPools). Delay pools allows you to limit traffic for clients or client groups:

```
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 1
delay_access 1 allow all
delay_parameters 1 64000/64000          # 512 kbits == 64 kbytes per second
```

Comment: Hi ooshro, 
Thanks for the quick reply. Will this limit the incoming and outgoing to 512kbits ? Is there any way I can verify it ?

Comment: @Supratik Limit only incoming. For outgoing use tc or iptables(hashlimit). To verify use http://www.speedtest.net/